# Arrays, List and Generics in Java

Tags: java, generics

Trying to fully understand Generics in Java, I ran into a problem I couldn't really get around, nor find a specific solution for in the web.
I have this method:

```
public <T extends City> void someMethod(List<T[]> objectsList) {
    List<City[]> myList = (List<City[]>) objectsList;
}
```

Just writing this into the compiler with provide me with an error I can ignore - however during compilation the compiler fails saying

```
Error:(97, 46) error: incompatible types: List<T[]> cannot be converted to List<City[]> where T is a type-variable: T extends City declared in method <T>someMethod(List<T[]>)
```

A simple solution is to simple run the entire List and Arrays within the received 'objectsList' and typecast them one at a time, which would work (I tried that), however I'm not really sure that's the right way to do it...

Comment: can you post some more code..post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: *A simple solution is to simple run the entire List and Arrays within the received 'objectsList' and typecast them one at a time, which would work*. I am scratching my head and wondering what exactly do you mean by this? Don't you think it would make more sense if you first told us what is that you want to do inside `someMethod`?

Comment: @Madhan:  That **is** a MCVE.

Comment: Why do you need `List<City[]> myList = ...`?

Comment: @Pshemo I needed to pass a 2 dimensional array to the method, doesn't really matter if via Array or a List

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't something you're going to want to do often (since generics and arrays don't mix well), but there are some important things to make note of:

- `T` holds the type information for the method.  You may not be passing in a `City` at all times, and in the off case you don't, Java can't help you out.
- The cast is not going to be safe, due to the fact that generics are invariant; you cannot say that a `List<City[]>` is equivalent to a `List<T[]>`, even if `T extends City`.

With that, what you can do to fix this is use a wildcard bound on the generic types.  Use them in both the declaration of what you accept to the method, and what you're storing.  You then avoid the cast, and everything is type-safe.

```
public <T extends City> void someMethod(List<? extends T[]> objectsList) {
    List<? extends T[]> myList =  objectsList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to cast - just work with arrays of type `T[]`. For example, this compiles:

```
public <T extends City> void someMethod(List<T[]> objectsList) {
    for (T[] cities : objectsList) {
        for (City city : cities) {
            // do something with the city object
        }
    }
}
```

The code in the method doesn't know which exact subclass of `City` is in the arrays, but you may assign them to a variable of type `City` and treat them as `City` objects.

---

The reason your cast doesn't work is due to the fact that `List<SubType>` is not a subtype of `List<Type>`.

Answer (score 0):

Because, in Java, an array is like a type. Ergo, the type `City[]` is completely different to `T extends City` I'm not sure what you're getting at, but that `List<T[]>` looks extremely dodgy.

**How To Use Generics**

Let's say you want to return an `ArrayList` in the reverse order to one parametrised. I don't know why, and I expect there's a perfectly good library function to do so, but let's roll with it.

```
public ArrayList<E> getReversedList(ArrayList<E> list) {
    ArrayList<E> newList = new ArrayList(list.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        newList.add(list.size() - i, (E) list.get(i));

    return newList;
}
```